# Insert data to textbox from firebase with options from a select form

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, html-select

**SOLVED! Check below for solution**

Hello so I need help on figuring out how this will go. This is the case:

[Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whbyT.png)

[Firebase Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMX6j.png)

Once the user selects a "Vehicle Number" on the list, the "VIN" and "Plate #" textboxes will automatically update with the corresponding data from the database.

In the example with the mock data, once the user selects "A_012", the VIN readonly textbox should only show "KIA9183891284" and the plate # should only show "KIA-0987".

This is currently the HTML and JS codes I used

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="vehinum">Vehicle Number</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="vehicle_num" id="vehinumInput">
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="vin">VIN</label>
   <input type="text" name="vin" class="form-control" id="vinInput" readonly="true">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="platenum">Plate #</label>
   <input type="text" name="plate_no" class="form-control" id="platenoInput" readonly="true">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref('vehicles').once('value', function(snapshot){
   if(snapshot.exists()){
      var vehi_list = '';
         snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var val = data.val();
            vehi_list += '<option value="' + val.vehicle_number + '">' + val.vehicle_number + '</option>';
         });

            $('#vehinumInput').append(vehi_list);

}
```

I really don't know how to move forward from here. So I am looking for advice or answers on how this will go.

Thank you for taking your time to read!

Comment: don't know if you can change value if you have `readonly true`, but I think you can do something like `document.querySelector('[name="vin"]').value = "xxxxx"`, this should populate VIN input field

Comment: yes that is alright and the "vin" value i got from using that is from the final entry in the database, not from the mock data above. my problem is where i get the "xxxxx" value. I am not sure how this will work. should I query the database on every time the user selects the "vehinum"? I am just very confused on what to do next to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So after a ton of research, I finally managed to find the answer**

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="vehi_num_mainte">
     <label for="exampleFormControlInput100">Vehicle Number</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="vehicle_num1" id="numberInput1" onchange="vehi_num_mainte_event();">
          <option>-- Select Vehicle --</option>
     </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleFormControlInput101">VIN</label>
     <input type="text" name="vin_maintenance" class="form-control" id="vinInput1" readonly="true">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleFormControlInput102">Plate #</label>
     <input type="text" name="plate_no1" class="form-control" id="platenoInput1" readonly="true">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function vehi_num_mainte_event()
            {
                //Get text or inner html of the selected option
                var d = document.getElementById("numberInput1");
                var selectedText = d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;

                firebase.database().ref('vehicles').child('vehicle_number').on('value', function(vehinumSnapshot) {
                    var vehinumChildSnapshot = vehinumSnapshot.val();

                    var queryRef = firebase.database().ref('vehicles').orderByChild('vehicle_number').equalTo(selectedText);
                        queryRef.on('value', function(querySnapshot) {
                            querySnapshot.forEach(function(dinoSnapshot) {
                            var vin_mainte = '';
                            var plate_mainte = '';
                            var val = dinoSnapshot.val();

                            vin_mainte += val.vin;
                            plate_mainte += val.plate_no;

                            document.getElementById('vinInput1').value = vin_mainte;
                            document.getElementById('platenoInput1').value = plate_mainte;
                        });

                    });

                });
            }
```

These were my references:

[Javascript HTML element get selected select option text value notepad ++](https://youtu.be/WNLC2b5AVIE)

[Firebase Docs (Retrieve Data)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)